# rails routing and active record error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, routes

I have a controller called employees.

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  def admission    
    @bank_fields = BankField.all.where(:status => true)
    if @bank_fields.empty?
      redirect_to  :action => "show", :id => @bank_fields.first.id
    end    
  end

  def show
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  end

  # The RESTful actions are as usual; I didn't give those here.
end
```

in the routes file

```
match ':controller/:action/:id', :via => [:get, :post,:put]

match ':controller/:action', :via => [:post, :get]

resources :employees
```

In the view I called the that admission action by

```
 <%= link_to 'admission', :controller => :employees, :action => :admission %>
```

but when i press the link i got the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /employees/admisson
 Couldn't find Employee with id=admisson
```

That means its hitting to the show action.Which i dont know why.Is there any solution.Thanks

Comment: You are missing an :id in your link_to.You should pass an :id.

Comment: thanks for the reply.I dont need the id actually.I want to redirect to  the 

     match ':controller/:action', :via => [:post, :get]

this path.But the rails routes is pointing to the 

     match ':controller/:action/:id', :via => [:post, :get]

which i dont want to.

Comment: currently you have records in bankfields with status=>true?

Comment: I have added my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments,if you want to redirect to the `match ':controller/:action', :via => [:post, :get]`,just edit your routes as below.

```
match ':controller/:action', :via => [:post, :get] #primary

match ':controller/:action/:id', :via => [:get, :post,:put] #secondary
```

Before you have

```
match ':controller/:action/:id', :via => [:get, :post,:put] #primary

match ':controller/:action', :via => [:post, :get] #secondary
```

So,the primary route demands an `:id` and you are not passing an `:id` in your `link_to`. So is the error.

Comment: @user3316484 Pleasure to help!

Comment: @user3316484 please accept the answer,if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

The routes in your route.rb file are a bit odd. Just use the generic way of specifying a custom action by adding it to the resources block:

```
resources :employees do
  collection do
    get :admission
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're not using Rails' [resourceful routing structure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) (which is the basis of how Rails calculates Routes):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :employees
   #-> get /employees, to: "employees#index"
   #-> get /employees/:id, to: "employees#show", id: :id
   #-> get /employees/new, to: "employees#new"
   #-> post /employees/new, to: "employees#create"
   #-> get /employees/:id/edit, to: "employees#edit"
   #-> patch /employees/:id, to: "employees#update"
   #-> delete /employees/:id, to: "employees#destroy"
```

You can use the `collection` method to give you "collective" routes (where *collections* of data are stored), or `member` routes (where *single* data records are handled):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :employees do
   get :admission, as: :collection
end
```

This is compounded with your abstinence from the [Rails path helpers](http://blog.kathrynblackley.com/post/72881624696/the-path-helpers-for-a-rails-resourceful-route), which will help you route your requests accordingly:

```
<%= link_to 'admission', employees_admission_path %>
```